# Firebase authentication Return null statement

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication

How can i manage to execute statement in condition when firebase-authentication return null statement during create user registration successfully..

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).catch(function(error) {

  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;

  if(errorCode == "auth/email-already-in-use"){ //condition working
    alert(errorMessage);
  }
  else if(errorCode == null){ //this condition not working
    alert("Registration Successfully");
  }
  else{  //condition working
    alert("Weak Password");
  }

});
```

Comment: What do you mean return null statement? You have to add .then(function(user){//successful}).catch(function(error){}); if you want to catch the user creation success.

Answer (score 0):

if you start new activity you have to check who is the Current User and if user is available you can start second Activity like this

```
 auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); // Get Firebase auth instance

    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Login_Activity.this, SecondActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
```

if any users not available you have to redirect user to login activity or user creating activity as you wish

```
authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user == null) {

                // user auth state is changed - user is null
                // launch login activity

                startActivity(new Intent(secondActivity.this, Login_Activity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: so how can i implement in javascript by handling the null statement ?
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user) {
  alert("have user");
} else {
  alert("no user");
}`

Comment: firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
    var uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
    // ...
  }
  // ...
});